# Node + Coffeescript + Zappa

Tags: node.js, frameworks, coffeescript

I have been looking around for the best framework with nodejs. I am starting to lean twords [Zappa](http://zappajs.org/). I was testing it out and everything was working fine until I started a new project and reinstalled it with npm.

Now any time I do anything with it, it throws this error.

This

```
require('zappa') ->
    console.log "Hello World!"
```

Becomes

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/giodamelio/Projects/node-boilerplate/node_modules/zappa/lib/zappa.js:65:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/giodamelio/Projects/node-boilerplate/node_modules/zappa/lib/zappa.js:702:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
at require (module.js:375:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/giodamelio/Projects/node-boilerplate/src/app.coffee:3:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/giodamelio/Projects/node-boilerplate/src/app.coffee:52:4)
```

What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I just had a similar problem with **zappa 0.3.3**

Apparently the creator of **zappa** is on vacation and doesn't update to the current versions of **node.js**, but you may use **zappajs** instead. It's a fork that is a little more up-to-date.

```
npm install zappajs
```

And use `require('zappajs')` instead of `require('zappa')`.

Comment: Thanks. Just for reference, here is the like to the github repo. https://github.com/zappajs/zappajs